# remove duplicate records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have userid and role id fields in the table. In that table couple userid's has two roles. But it shouldn't.

example:

```
Userid(FK)    RoleID(FK)
1             1E36A840-2EBB-44EC-8861-0E3D262AC676
1             0B54F223-E0D4-4CFC-84C3-7C98C1BFC6DA
2             1E36A840-2EBB-44EC-8861-0E3D262AC676
3             0B54F223-E0D4-4CFC-84C3-7C98C1BFC6DA
4             1E36A840-2EBB-44EC-8861-0E3D262AC676
4             0B54F223-E0D4-4CFC-84C3-7C98C1BFC6DA
```

In this case I have to delete 1 and 4 where '1E36A840-2EBB-44EC-8861-0E3D262AC676' which has '0B54F223-E0D4-4CFC-84C3-7C98C1BFC6DA'

Comment: How do you decide which Role to keep?

Comment: Why shouldn't a user have multiple roles?

Comment: Based on the [OP's "answer"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317485/remove-duplicate-records/5317626#5317626), I vote to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent this from happening in the first place by putting a unique constraint on the `Userid` column.  However, before doing this you will need to remove existing duplicates.  Given the information we have so far (a `Userid` and a `Roleid`) there's really no way to "correctly" do this.  As @Joe Stefanelli mentioned in his comment, you'd need to decide which role is the "correct" one for each user.  That sounds like a manual process.  (Unless you know ahead of time that only the first one should be kept in each case, in which case @Thomas has a good answer.)

Out of curiosity, is there a specific reason why a user can't (or shouldn't, in this case) have multiple roles?  Usually that's what roles are for, applying multiple permission sets, etc. to various users in a many-to-many fashion.  Think of it in terms of object-oriented design.  Roles are interfaces (types) and users are classes (implementations).  By having multiple roles, each user can be polymorphic into multiple user types throughout the system.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server 2005 and later and assuming we have a primary key column (called PKCol in this example) and assuming it does not matter which RoleId is removed:

```
With Dups As
    (
    Select PKCol
        , Row_Number() Over( Partition By UserId Order By PKCol ) As Num
    From Table
    )
Delete MyTable
From MyTable As T1
    Join Dups As T2
        On T2.PKCol = T1.PKCol
Where T2.Num > 1
```